# Change the eye of a dice

Tags: java, dice

School gave me the assignment to make a dice game where the user can change the eye of the Dice, the only hint they gave me was using the ASCII table..

This is my code so far and i'm hitting a brick wall as how i can make the numbers be the input of the user (I'm not very creative):

```
 System.out.println("Which character should be used as the eye of the dice:");
    char eyeDice = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(eyeDice);


    int Dice;
    Dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);

    while (Dice < 6) {
        Dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);
        System.out.println(Dice);

    }
```

The output of the code looks as follows:

```
Which character should be used as the eye of the dice:
$
$
1
4
1
1
1
1
4
1
2
2
6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is what it should end up looking like:

```
Which character should be used as the eye of the dice:

#
  #
    #

#   #
  #
#   #

#   #

#   #
#   #
#   #


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any tips or hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Type out the various numerical values a die (singular of dice) can have.  Then, write static print statements to generate each number.  After this, see how you can convert user input into one of these print statements.

Comment: I don't understand how the expected output relates to what you have? Also what does `eye of the dice` mean?

Comment: @dustytrash the output of the code is supposed to generate a random number between 1 and 6. when it hits 6 it should stop. the assignment also requires the output of the code to not be numbers, but rather the character the user inputs. So far i've made the while loop with the Math.random function, all theres left for me to do is create the little dots of the dice and make those be the character the user inserts.

Does that clear it up?

so for example:

# -> 1
#   # -> 2

#
   #
      # -> 3

#   #
#   # -> 4

so fort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers do not ship with code to turn the digit '4' into an ascii drawing.

You'd have to write this yourself. I suggest drawing these out on a piece of paper. In your java code, you can have a bunch of if/elseif statements, one for each of the 6 faces. Each block would print 3 lines. Start by locking in the character to use for the eye, then work on making that something the user can configure later.

Here's part of it to get you started:

```
if (dieRoll == 5) {
    System.out.println("* *");
    System.out.println(" * ");
    System.out.println("* *");
} else if (dieRoll == 6) {
    // you figure it out from here...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given example the `eyeDice` was `'#'`. And the thrown `dice` (please with a small `d` in java) would be 3, 5, 4 and 6.

Hence you need some method like:

```
void printDice(int dice, char eyDice) {
    ... System.out.println ...
}
```

and your code

```
int dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);

while (dice < 6) {
    printDice(dice, eyeDice);
    dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1)
}
```

A 5 would be printed (ignoring the eye):

```
System.out.println("?   ?");
System.out.println("  ?  ");
System.out.println("?   ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full example but it was to give you an idea of what to do

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Which character should be used as the eye of the dice:");
    char eyeDice = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(eyeDice);


    int Dice;
    Dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);

    while (Dice < 6) {
        Dice = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);
        System.out.println(Dice);
        //If statement calling print
    }
}

private void printOne(char character){
    String dice = "\n  #  \n";
    System.out.println(dice.replace('#', character));
}

private void printTwo(char character){
    String dice = "#   #\n\n#   #";
    System.out.println(dice.replace('#', character));
}

private void printThree(char character){
    String dice = "#\n  #\n   #";
    System.out.println(dice.replace('#', character));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have your answer, but another possible solution is to use an ENUM. E.G:

```
public class Dice 
{
    private enum DieFace
    {
        ONE('1', "   \n * \n   "),
        TWO('2', "*  \n   \n  *"),
        THREE('3', "*  \n * \n  *"),
        FOUR('4', "* *\n   \n* *"),
        FIVE('5', "* *\n * \n* *"),
        SIX('6', "* *\n* *\n* *");

        private char characterCode;
        private String representation;

        DieFace(char characterCode, String representation)
        {
            this.characterCode = characterCode;
            this.representation = representation;
        }

        public static DieFace getDieFaceFromCharacterCode(char characterCode)
        {
            DieFace dieFaceFound = null;

            for (DieFace dieFace : values())
            {
                if (dieFace.characterCode == characterCode)
                {
                    dieFaceFound = dieFace;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return dieFaceFound;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return this.representation;
        }
    }

    public static String getDieFaceFromCharacter(char characterInput)
    {
        DieFace dieFace = DieFace.getDieFaceFromCharacterCode(characterInput);

        return dieFace == null ? null : dieFace.toString();
    }
}
```

And here's a test for the class:

```
public class DieTest 
{
    @Test
    public void testGetOne()
    {
        String expectedResult = "   \n * \n   ";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('1'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetTwo()
    {
        String expectedResult = "*  \n   \n  *";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('2'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetThree()
    {
        String expectedResult = "*  \n * \n  *";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('3'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFour()
    {
        String expectedResult = "* *\n   \n* *";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('4'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFive()
    {
        String expectedResult = "* *\n * \n* *";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('5'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSix()
    {
        String expectedResult = "* *\n* *\n* *";
        assertEquals(expectedResult, Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('6'));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetInvalid()
    {
        // < 1 is invalid
        assertNull(Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('0'));

        // invalid character (non-number)
        assertNull(Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('a'));

        // > 6 is invalid
        assertNull(Dice.getDieFaceFromCharacter('7'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple dice program

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Program
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Random input =new Random();
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
    int c =input.nextInt(b-a)+a;

    switch(a){
       case 2:
       System.out.println("*");
       break;
       case 5:
       System.out.println("*  *");
       break;
       case 6:
       System.out.println("* \n * \n  *");
       break;
      case 4:
       System.out.println("*  * \n*  *");
       break;
       case 1:
       System.out.println("*   *\n  *\n*   *");
       break;
       case 3:
       System.out.println(" *  *  *\n\n *  *  *");
       break;


           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you're looking to minimize reuse, you could use a switch statement. E.G:

```
public class Dice 
{
    private static final String LINE_BREAK = "\n";
    public static String getDieFaceFromCharacter(char characterInput)
    {
        String top = "   ";
        String middle = "   ";
        String bottom = "   ";

        switch(characterInput)
        {
            case '5':
                top = "* *";
                bottom = "* *";
            case '1':
                middle = " * ";
                break;
            case '3':
                top = "*  ";
                middle = " * ";
                bottom = "  *";
                break;
            case '2':
                top = "*  ";
                bottom = "  *";
                break;
            case '6':
                middle = "* *";
            case '4':
                top = "* *";
                bottom = "* *";
        }

        return top + LINE_BREAK + middle + LINE_BREAK + bottom;
    }
}
```